# Symfony 4 - how dependecy injection works

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

Using **Symfony 3.4** we call services like so:  `$container->get('service.name')`
so we make sure to give names to our services.
in **Symfony 4** we inject services by `class name` or `interface` directly in the controller like so:

```
public function someAction(HttpClientInterface $service){
   // do something here
}
```

so what confuses me here is that we are injecting an interface and symfony takes care of invoking the right object in the controller.
**my question is**: if I have 2 services that implements the same interface :

```
class ClassA implements InterfaceX{}
class ClassB implements InterfaceX{}
```

and in the controller I do this:

```
public function someAction(InterfaceX $service){
   // do something here
}
```

which service gets invoked ?

Comment: Reference: [*Dealing with Multiple Implementations of the Same Type*](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#dealing-with-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-type)

Comment: @Yoshi oh I see :), thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, services can implement the same interface and in your controller you will need to inject correct service, like this:

```
public function someAction(ClassA $serviceA){
   // do something here
}
```

and

```
public function someOtherAction(ClassB $serviceB){
   // do something here
}
```

If you need same service in multiple methods on the same class, use Dependency Injection on the __construct

Comment: @SlimenTN - It is what it is.  Using a class/interface name is quite handy but does not cover every possibility.  It is possible to create an alias and explicitly map an interface to a particular implementation.  Think of it as the default implementation.  You can also gather up all the implementations into a service locator and inject it.  You would then pull a specific service from the locator. And while it does not work for action injection, you can manually inject a specific implementation into your controller.